# Trying to upload images but they don't appear in the destination folder

Tags: java, eclipse

My uploaded images save to `webapp/projectName/uploadedImage.folder`. However, they don't show in my Eclipse navigator project `uploadedImage.folder`.

How can I get data from there in to my project?

Also, is it safe to save all uploaded data to webapp?

I'm new to Java.

Comment: Can you actually check on the filesystem that the images exist in the folder? Maybe you "think" they have been saved to the folder but they actually don't exist?

Comment: On a side note, saving user data, which I am assuming is the case you have described, to the webapp root, is NOT good practice. Any user or application data should be outside the webapp root so that it can persist across different versions/deployments of the webapp

Comment: they are saved to that folder and i can download them also but doesnt appear on my project folder

Answer (score 0):

select the folder and press F5 to refresh in eclipse.

Comment: which perspective do you use?

Comment: My uploaded images save to (webapp/projectName/uploadedImage.folder) i want that images should b show on my project folder

Comment: which eclipse-persective do you use? try Window->Open Perspective -> Resource